# How to have multiple stop losses / profit takers in pinescript (pyramiding)

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I am trying to create multiple stops/profit takers for my strategy. However, once a 2nd position is added (for example 2 longs (but can be infinite longs or shorts)) the stop parameter which is set to be the low of the entry candle is moved to the low of the 2nd long positions entry candle, causing me to be stopped out of both positions at once. The goal is to have an independent stop and profit target for every single trade signal. My little knowledge with java would suggest to use something like a counter with arrays to store values but I don't have a clear idea of how it would be done and experimenting for the past couple of hours hasn't gotten me far. Any help or direction would be amazing and let me know if you require further details.
Here is my current code with just the one stop loss/profit taker: as you can see the variables for sl and pt are overwritten

```
strategy("My Script"), overlay=true

//filters
timezone = input(title="Timezone", type=input.session, defval="0950-1500")
days = input(title="Days To Trade", defval="23456")

inSession(sess) => na(time(timeframe.period, sess + ":" + days)) == false

//identify engulfing candle
bullishEC = close >= high[1] and close[1] < open[1]
bearishEC = close <= low[1] and close[1] > open[1]

//get ema user input
emaLength1 = input(title="EMA 1 Length", type=input.integer, defval=110)

//get ema
ema1 = ema(close, emaLength1)

//plot ema
plot(ema1, color=close > ema1 ? color.green : color.red, linewidth=2)

//macd parameter
[macdline, signalline, macdhist] = macd(close, 12,26,9) //built in function

bearishM = macdline < signalline
bullishM = macdline > signalline


tradeSignal = ((close >= ema1) and bullishEC) or ((close < ema1) and bearishEC)

plotshape(tradeSignal and bearishEC and bearishM and barstate.isconfirmed and 
inSession(timezone), title="bearish", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, 
style=shape.triangledown, text="Sell")
plotshape(tradeSignal and bullishEC and bullishM and barstate.isconfirmed and 
inSession(timezone), title="bullish", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, 
style=shape.triangleup, text="Buy")


alertcondition(tradeSignal and bullishEC and bullishM, title="BUY SIGNAL", message="GO LONG 
on {{ticker}}")
alertcondition(tradeSignal and bearishEC and bearishM, title="SHORT SIGNAL", message="GO SHORT 
on {{ticker}}")

//setting stop & targets for current trade
var shortStopPrice = 0.0
var shortTargetPrice = 0.0
var shortStopDistance = 0.0
var longStopPrice = 0.0
var longTargetPrice = 0.0
var longStopDistance = 0.0


if (tradeSignal and bullishEC and bullishM and barstate.isconfirmed and inSession(timezone))
    longStopPrice := low 
    longStopDistance := close - longStopPrice
    longTargetPrice := close + (longStopDistance * 2)
    strategy.entry(id="long", long=strategy.long)


if (tradeSignal and bearishEC and bearishM and barstate.isconfirmed and inSession(timezone))
    shortStopPrice := high 
    shortStopDistance := shortStopPrice - close
    shortTargetPrice := close - (shortStopDistance * 2)
    strategy.entry(id="short", long=strategy.short)


//exit trade when stop or target is hit
strategy.exit("id=exit", from_entry="short", limit=shortTargetPrice, stop=shortStopPrice)
strategy.exit("id=exit", from_entry="long", limit=longTargetPrice, stop=longStopPrice)
//@version=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional orders require new strategy.entry calls and a unique trade identifier. Running a loop and using arrays is possible to achieve this, however if you are only going to do two perhaps its easier to just make 2 of everything. Please note that the second entry you speak of moving your stops is due to how you allow re-initialization of the stop values on another long alert. An example of how you may isolate the first set from the other set would be adding a positional check to the entry condition ifs like "and strategy.position_size == 0". This way the first set of stops only gets assigned on the first entry. You could also use a built in like "strategy.opentrades" to count how many are open and assign them only under 1,2, or 3 positions open etc.

Another tip would be to plot your exits and stops so we can see whats happening, where its happening, and why. We could plot conditional to position size so we only see the levels if in a position for example.

Also there is a "pyramiding" parameter both in the settings and one we can specify in the strategy() header to specify how many trades are allowed open at a time.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, I have tried to implement some of your recommendations by creating arrays to store the independent entries/stops/profit targets as I do sometimes have 6+ open orders at once so just duplicating would be inefficient. However, I'm running into different errors. I have made a new post about it and if you had a few minutes it would be awesome if you could check it out. Regardless, thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: Only if you give me points for the last answer! Jk Ill have a look when I get some time. Take care